# WooCommerce - Avoid adding same product if linked to different category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have same product linked to different sub-category and I need save them separately and not adding in to cart/checkout etc…

I think the good way is to save them with variation named **`"category_name"`** with value **`[$product_category]`** to differentiate them in the loop and showing them in the cart/checkout pages like in this example :

```css
Room_1 (main category)
Wall_works (subcategory)
Cleaning_windows hours Q.ty 4 (product)
———————————————————————————————————————
Room_2 (main category)
Wall_works (subcategory)
Cleaning_windows hours Q.ty 8 (product)
———————————————————————————————————————
Room_3 (main category)
Wall_works (subcategory)
Cleaning_windows hours Q.ty 8 (product)
```

And NOT like now as this *(in 1 line)*:

```css
Cleaning_windows hours Q.ty 20
```

I found online, this snippet for retrieving the **`main_category`** name but I dont know how use and save the value, and how to show it in cart/checkout like in my example above:

```
// retrieve category name
function get_product_category_by_id( $category_id ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $category_id, 'product_cat', 'ARRAY_A' );
    return $term['name'];
}

$prod_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($prod_terms as $prod_term) {

    // gets product cat id
    $product_cat_id = $prod_term->term_id;

    // gets an array of all parent category levels
    $product_parent_categories_all_hierachy = get_ancestors(    $product_cat_id, 'product_cat' );  

    // This cuts the array and extracts the last set in the array
    $last_parent_cat = array_slice($product_parent_categories_all_hierachy, -1, 1, true);
        foreach($last_parent_cat as $last_parent_cat_value){
        // $last_parent_cat_value is the id of the most top level category, can be use whichever one like

    }
}

$product_category = get_product_category_by_id( $last_parent_cat_value );
```

I need to create product variation with **`value => $product_category`** saved by default in all products when added to cart, without creating/inserting variations for all products (when created in back end) and without showing this variation in simple product page (front end).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: Done. Add } for function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields. Thanks.

Comment: I solved with this plugin [link](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/) that consent to create a variation for ALL products in 1 time and show them in to cart&chechout pages.